# Publishing an update to my app: "application already exists" message

Tags: android, google-play

I'm publishing an app on android market. Before updating it to a new version I installed the old version on my android. After that I uploaded the new version and waited for the market app to tell me that there were an update to my app. Now i'm clicking on "update" on my app and and it's showing the following message:

> application already exists

Does anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE

The problem solved itself. I'm guessing that it takes some time before the app update is updated across all google servers, so I was probably pushing the old version from a out-of-date server and when it was updated, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you've installed the older version which was signed with a debug key when APK for Android market is signed with a release key. So Android system cannot update the application.

Comment: I mentioned that I downloaded the app from android market before publishing the update, so that was not the problem. The problem was magically solved just now. I'm guessing that it takes some time before the app update is updated across all google servers, so I was probably pushing the old version from the server and it just got updated right now. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: You are right. Even the error message in situation I've described is different.